# How can I generate HEX-encoded CMAC-AES digest in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, oauth-2.0

I need to generate HEX encoded CMAC-AES digest using Node.JS. I have found [library from GitHub](https://github.com/allan-stewart/node-aes-cmac). I want to know how to call it?  [This](http://developer.pearson.com/learningstudio/course-apis/authentication/oauth2/sample-code) is the part I want to do it in node.js. I want to pass `key` and `message`.

I imported this library into my node.js project. I want to know how to call this method `aesCmac`.

My index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');
var aesCmac = require('./lib/aes-cmac.js');

var app = express();

app.get('/aesCmac', aesCmac.aesCmac('xxxxxxxx' ,'LSCourse|0xxxxxxxx|103xxxxxxxx|xxxxx|xxxx.xxx.xx@xxx.com|2014-11-11T09:29:04Z'));

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.listen(80);
```

I got this error:

```
F:\NODE.JS\node-aes-cmac-master>node index.js
node-crypto : Invalid key length 32

crypto.js:315
  this._binding.initiv(cipher, toBuf(key), toBuf(iv));
                ^
Error: error:0607A082:digital envelope routines:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length
    at new Cipheriv (crypto.js:315:17)
    at Object.Cipheriv (crypto.js:313:12)
    at aes128 (F:\NODE.JS\node-aes-cmac-master\lib\aes-cmac.js:25:23)
    at Object.exports.generateSubkeys (F:\NODE.JS\node-aes-cmac-master\lib\aes-cmac.js:9:11)
    at Object.exports.aesCmac (F:\NODE.JS\node-aes-cmac-master\lib\aes-cmac.js:32:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\NODE.JS\node-aes-cmac-master\index.js:9:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I am new to Node js.

Answer (score 2):

The [test file](https://github.com/allan-stewart/node-aes-cmac/blob/master/test/aes-cmac.js) shows how it can be used. You can't simply plug `aesCmac.aesCmac` into `app.get`. You need to handle the request and send the response.

```
// some hex encoded 512bit key
var key = new Buffer('2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c', 'hex');
var msg = new Buffer('LSCourse|0xxxxxxxx|103xxxxxxxx|xxxxx|xxxx.xxx.xx@xxx.com|2014-11-11T09:29:04Z');

app.get('/aesCmac', function(req, res){
  var result = aesCmac.aesCmac(key, msg);
  res.status(200).send(result.toString('hex'));
});
```

Comment: Do we need to pass message inside Buffer method ? can't we pass directly?

Comment: Yes, it must be a `Buffer`.

Comment: it always generating & return same value. & this algorithm  , doesn't much with  `http://developer.pearson.com/learningstudio/course-apis/authentication/oauth2/sample-code` this one

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with oauth and can't help you there. Technically you didn't ask about oauth, but rather how to use that library.